# Wix in TFSBuild: SourceCodeControlRoot

Tags: tfs, msbuild, wix

I am following the recommendations to integrate Wix with TFS (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html) (without having to install it on the Build server)

In my WixProj file, I have the line: 
$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\3.9\

This has been checked in with all of the prerequisite files - and I can successfully build on my Dev box.

But when I run my build, TFS complains that it can't find my Wix.targets file.

The error states:

*C:\Builds\8\AppName\DailyBuild\Sources\Setup\Case Tracking Setup\Wix Case Tracking.wixproj (73): The imported project "C:\wix\3.9\Wix.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

So I'm obviously using the wrong Reference but I couldn't find any other examples and the only place with SourceCodeControlRoot appears is related to Wix.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: A bit more on this: - 
When I look at how the Build is interpreting this line,
$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\3.9\
It is turning it simply into C:\wix\3.9. But then even in the Wix project when it attempts to build it, it does the same thing.

Shouldn't it be doing something more elaborate like my actual Source directory? It sounds like the constant is off.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article intends that you define or replace `$(SourceCodeControlRoot)` such that `$(SourceCodeControlRoot)` is the folder TFS exports to during the build. In your case, I'm guessing "C:\Builds\8\AppName\DailyBuild\". Of course, you probably don't want to hardcode it. You could pass a property setting to msbuild: `/property:SourceCodeControlRoot="$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)"`

It doesn't really matter where you have your binaries (wix\3.9) folder. The end goal is to have $(WixToolPath) point to it. You could define it relative the project file if that's more convenient in your project structure:

```
<WixToolPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../wix/3.9/</WixToolPath>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom - that makes sense that if it wasn't defined, it would give these results.

So I could likely just use $(SolutionDir) as it should apply to both MSBuild and VS. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. (But, of course, if you use msbuild to build a project instead of a solution, SolutionDir won't be defined.)